# what is total number of objects in Oracle DB?

Tags: database, oracle

Can anyone tell me what is the total number of objects in Oracle database?
From number I mean count of oracle objects.

Regards,
Hamd

Comment: How many have you created?

Comment: Objects you means? even table is a object as per oracle!

Comment: `select count(*) from dba_objects`

Comment: well I was asked the question in a telephonic interview, I am Java Programmer, but Oracle was mentioned in my CV. but they asked the question about the total number of object in oracle database. I know table and user etc are objects but don't know it's count..

Comment: select object_type,count(*) from dba_objects group by object_type makes more sense. it categorize all the objects types available and their count. You could possibly ommit the synonyms as they are just names for the objects! Good luck. Sorry for bad formatting!

Comment: Thank you all for showing your interests and replies.....

Comment: Of all the questions I might think to ask in an interview, that is one of the most pointless.  Although I suppose it does probe knowledge of the data dictionary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Number of objets group by owner.

```
select count(*), 
       owner 
  from dba_objects 
 group by owner;
```

### Number of objects group by object type, filtered by owner

```
 select count(*), owner, object_type 
   from dba_objects 
  where owner= '?????????' 
group by owner, object_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Version: Number of objects per user**

```
  SELECT a.username
        ,COUNT(b.object_name)
    FROM sys.dba_users a
         LEFT JOIN sys.dba_objects b ON a.username = b.owner
GROUP BY a.username
ORDER BY a.username;
```